# Ignore certain directories in docker volume mapping

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have an application that saves the data in the container directory **/var/lib/app-data**.

This container directory should be backed up since the application makes changes to the **/var/lib/app-data** content regularly as it runs.

But need to backup only specific directories and files under /var/lib/app-data/

For ex Below are the files and directories should be backed up regularly under /var/lib/app-data/,so even if the container stopped, the new container still get this files and directories.

- /var/lib/app-data/ui_log/
- /var/lib/app-data/node_log/
- /var/lib/app-data/users/mailer.xml
- /var/lib/app-data/plugins/

Other files and directories should not be backed up to volumes.

Currently I could able to find out only one way to map docker volume like below.

```
docker run -v forkuidatavolume:/var/lib/app-data mohan/forkui:1.0
```

But above step backing up directories other than one mentioned above. 
Is it possible to backup specific container files and directories using -v or any other way?

Thanks,

Mohan

Answer (score 0):

You can put a list of files that you do not want to be added to your docker image at `.dockerignore`. For example:

```
.git
/tmp/*
/var/lib/app-data/ui_log/*
/var/lib/app-data/node_log/
/var/lib/app-data/users/mailer.xml
/var/lib/app-data/plugins/*
```

or you can use multiple volumes and link them to your `tmp` like this:

```
docker run -v /var/lib/app-data/ui_log/:/tmp/ui_log -v /var/lib/app-data/node_log/:/tmp/node_log ... mohan/forkui:1.0
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I need to igone certian files and directiories while backing up data from container to docker volumes. your answer is ignore files and directories while building docker image